# keep only certain values in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm essentially trying to filter this massive US Census data frame by zip-codes that I want ONLY. I'm using tidycensus just to be as specific as possible.

```
   GEOID NAME        variable  value
   <chr> <chr>       <chr>     <dbl>
 1 77477 ZCTA5 77477 PCT023003 13615
 2 77478 ZCTA5 77478 PCT023003 13260
 3 77479 ZCTA5 77479 PCT023003 38546
 4 77480 ZCTA5 77480 PCT023003  6397
 5 77481 ZCTA5 77481 PCT023003     5
 6 77482 ZCTA5 77482 PCT023003  1832
 7 77483 ZCTA5 77483 PCT023003   277
 8 77484 ZCTA5 77484 PCT023003  8297
 9 77485 ZCTA5 77485 PCT023003  3063
10 77486 ZCTA5 77486 PCT023003  5461
```

the df looks like this, I just want to be able to select certain ZCTA5 values, which I know already.

Comment: You probably want `%in%`, as in `x[ x$NAME %in% c("ZCTA5 77477", "ZCTA5 77484"),]`. Or `grepl`, as in `x[ grepl(" 7748[0-9]$", x$NAME),]`.

Comment: which are those "certain ZCTA5 values" ? Did you try @r2evans's suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code and replace the values inside `c()`. I assume your dataset name is "dataset":

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% filter(NAME %in% c("ZCTA5 77477", "ZCTA5 77484"))
```

Regards,

Manu

Comment: I cant use the filter function as when I import tidy verse the dplyr::filter() portion shows an X, and that it no longer supports the filter() function

Comment: If you mean a red "X" it means that it conflicts with another function named `filter` but you can use `dataset %>% dplyr::filter(NAME %in% c("ZCTA5 77477", "ZCTA5 77484"))`

Comment: Nothing in the OP though *requires* the `tidyverse`: `%in%` works just fine with base, and if you really need subsetting without all the dollar-indexing, then `subset(mtcars, cyl %in% c(4, 6))` (base R) is just as readable (and still works with `%>%` if you like that). (Speaking of that, please consider being specific with what your answer needs: for somebody who doesn't know R or the tidyverse very well, you're loading over two dozen packages just for `filter`, which is likely already loaded based on the `tibble` presentation in the OP.)